# OSX: Execute same command on all files within a folder

Tags: macos, command-line, image-compression, command-line-tool

i am using a command-line tool called TMX (https://github.com/tonybeltramelli/TMXResolutionTool)
I want to execute this command on **every .png file** in a certain folder. How can i do that?

This is how it is used:

```
TMXResolutionTool <tmx path> <resize ratio>
TMXResolutionTool <image path> <resize ratio>
TMXResolutionTool <image path> <new width> <new height>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
find <path> -name "*.png" | xargs -Irepl TMXResolutionTool repl <ratio>
```

If you need to run all those commands in order on each file before moving to the next, a small bash script may be clearer

```
find <path> -name "*.png" | while read f ; do 
TMXResolutionTool $f <resize ratio> ; 
TMXResolutionTool $f <resize ratio> ;
TMXResolutionTool $f <new width> <new height> ; done
```

Answer (score 24):

I think a `for/do` loop is clearer and probably a little faster than `find` plus `xargs`.  Assuming you are using the default shell, `bash`, on OS X, the general form of the command if you want to do it as a one-liner is:

```
for f in <files>; do <somecommand> $f; done
```

where `<files>` is an expression that evaluates to a list of files (usually a wildcard expansion), `<somecommand>` is the command line that you want executed for each file, and `$f` expands to each file in `<files>` in turn.  So you'd type something like this:

```
for f in myfolder/*; do TMXResolutionTool $f <otherparameters> ; done
```

You can also run multiple commands inside the loop on the same line just by chaining them with semicolons.  So, if your question means that you want to run TMXResolutionTool three times on each file in sequence with different parameters:

```
for f in myfolder/*; do TMXResolutionTool $f <otherparameters>; TMXResolutionTool $f <differentparameters>; TMXResolutionTool $f <yetmoredifferentstuff>; done
```

By the way, this is all basic `bash` shell tricks; it's not specific to OS X.  Any book on `bash` will tell you all this and more (although if you want to learn about the command line from a Mac perspective, I recommend the O'Reilly book [Learning Unix for OS X Mountain Lion](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025870.do)).

Comment: Note if you want to run the command on all the files in the current folders just use `*` (e.g. `for f in *`)